# Linkedin Login Using oAuth 1.0a

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm working on linkedin Api using oAuth 2.0 in swift. The main problem is that it did't write cookies in `UIWebView` after getting `access_token`.
I tried this `

```
oginWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string : "https://www.instagram.com/")!))
```

after getting `access_token` but display login page not `/feed` page. I need cookies for my app. I checked many post but did't get any proper solution for authentication in oAuth 1.0a.
I'm using Instagram `oauth` and it also gives me cookies. I think it due to `oAuth 1.0`. I did't have much knowledge about oAuth.

Can any one give me simple login example(swift, objective-c) of linkedin authentication in webview using oAuth 1.0a. Or any other solution for save cookie. Or how i can use below code for linkedin.
Thanks .
[oAuth 1.0 Sample](http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html)

```
struct INSTAGRAM_IDS {

    static let INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
    static let INSTAGRAM_APIURl  = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
    static let INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID  = ""
    static let INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET = ""
    static let INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI = ""
    static let INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN =  "access_token"
    static let INSTAGRAM_SCOPE = "likes+comments+relationships+public_content+follower_list"
}

 func unSignedRequest () {
        let authURL = String(format: "%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True", arguments: [INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI, INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_SCOPE ])
        let urlRequest =  URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: authURL)!)
        loginWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

    func checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: URLRequest) -> Bool {

        let requestURLString = (request.url?.absoluteString)! as String

        if requestURLString.hasPrefix(INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI) {
            print(requestURLString, "RedirectURL")
            let range: Range<String.Index> = requestURLString.range(of: "#access_token=")!
            handleAuth(authToken: requestURLString.substring(from: range.upperBound))
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false;
        }
        return true
    }

    func handleAuth(authToken: String)  {
        print("Instagram authentication token ==", authToken)
        downloadImage(url: URL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token=\(authToken)")!)
}

 func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        return checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: request)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
import Foundation

let headers = [
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

Be sure to change the querystring parameters in `NSURL`. The response headers will return with cookies' data inside them.